# Which are the steps to import a text file and an Excel file on Modelica?

Tags: excel, text, modelica, openmodelica

I'm having a little trouble here. I want to use data for my model from two files: one with extension .txt and other one with extension .csv. Then I want to have access to that especific data to process it as parameters. Do I have to use a function? What would be your take on this topic? Thank you!

PD: I'm using OpenModelica.

I've tried the ExternData library but I think I don´t get it quite right.

`fileName=Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource("modelica:/Files/Examples/CSVReader/Data.csv"),`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `ExternData` library is a pretty good choice. It supports both file-types and should do what you want - although the question is a bit fuzzy in that regard.

Did you take a look at `ExternData.Examples.CSVTest`? That should explain how the library is used. Basically, it is a two-step process:

1. You use the `dataSource` class to specify the path to the file as well as the file-type.
2. Then you access the data via the respective functions (re)-declared in the `dataSource`, e.g. `dataSource.getRealArray2D(3, 2)` with the integers defining the size of the matrix that is read.

For more details: https://ecp.ep.liu.se/index.php/modelica/article/view/189.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! Well, what I want to do is use a text file with 5 rows and 5 columns and then create a model using data from each row. I'm taking a look at External.Data but it dosen't support text files :/ I think I'll have to use CombiTable.